# Go back on line with left arrow when using read?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm reading from stdin with `read var`. When I type something, I can't go back in the line by pressing the left arrow on the keyboard. I get `test[[D^[[D^[[D` (three presses to the left arrow). How can this be solved?

Seems like a question that was probably asked before, but I didn't get any results on the SO suggestions and my Google-fu failed me.

Answer (score 7):

The ability to use arrow keys to move the cursor around within the text you've entered is provided by [the readline library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). bash's `read` command doesn't use readline by default, but you can tell it to do so by providing the `-e` option. So just add that option to your `read` command.